# Change button color without declaring member variable

Tags: c++, c, mfc, visual-c++

I am trying to color the button by using `CColorbutton` class function `setcolor`. It is working fine when I have declared the member variable of button but it is not working when I directly get the handle by `GetDlgItem(IDC_BUTTON1)`. Can anyone tell me the solution of this?

CColorButton* pWnd = (CColorButton*)GetDlgItem(id+i);
pWnd->SetColor(RGB(0,0,0),RGB(200, 153, 204));

Comment: Please edit your post and include the code you have tried. This works fine for me: `CMFCColorButton* cb = (CMFCColorButton*)GetDlgItem(IDC_MFCCOLORBUTTON1); cb->SetColor(RGB(255,255,0));`

Comment: thank you for reply Ove. but i am using CColorButton Class instead of CMFCColorButton because i am using Visual studio 2005 and it doesn't have CMFCColorButton class

Comment: Where did you get the CColorButton from? I don't have it in my Visual Studio installation, that's why I used CMFCColorButton, because it was the closest thing. Anyway, I think that your problem is that you aren't providing the correct id for GetDlgItem(). The value `id+i` doesn't look right to me. Any control in the form designer must have an ID. You can see that ID by right-clicking the control, and choosing properties. Please use that ID instead of `id+i` and see if that works.

Comment: Mfc is not compatible with c. So why use both tags?

Comment: @Ove actually i need to change color of around 90 buttons and their id are consecutive so i have used for loop for that. CColorButton is third party class for changing color of button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: Without declaring a variable for the button control you will not get it to run!

Why? A window Variable and using DDX-Control or using CWNd::SubclassWindow is the way, subclassing works in the MFC. Without subclassing the messages are not handled by the code that is used in CCOlorButton.

Yes you can use GetDlgItem and my do a hard cast to CColorButton, but this is extremely dangerous! Why? The window object you get is just a temporary CWnd object with no additional member variables. If you call a specific member function of a CColorButton, that uses additional data members you may destroy your memory/heap/stack content.

With a MFC control class you always need the specific object somewhere in memory to suavely cast a pointer that GetDlgItem returns!

If you have a member function you don't need a cast. If (for any other reason) you need to cast a CWnd pointer, it is wise to use STATIC_DOWNCAST/DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST to get ASSERTs when something is wrong.

Comment: Semi-correct. Most MFC controls (`CEdit`, `CButton`, `CTreeView`, etc.) have a single class member, a `HWND` identifying the native control. You do not need a member variable for any of these nor do you need to subclass them. This is usually only required for 3rd-party control implementations.

Comment: I see no error in my explanation. But thank you for you further assist.

Comment: i agree with your answer but  have around 90 button controls so for changing color of all button color declaring member variable for all button control is not a good idea so i am trying from getdlgitem

Comment: You don't need to declare one. It is allowed to construct them on the heap and either you track the pointer in an array to delete them later, or you create/derive a new class and implement PostNCDestroy and insert a **delete this;**. If you use the second approach the class can't be used any langer as a member variable and must be created oin the heap like a frame or view...

Answer (score 0):

If you do not declare and properly initialize a CColorButton variable then there is no CColorButton object in your program. So you are calling something that does not exist. You asked for the solution of this, but you already know the solution!